# How to get the json data that sent over curl to the server

Tags: php, curl

I have a curl script that post json data to test.php but in test.php I cannot print the data sent.  I don't know if its working properly.  How do I retrive the data sent ?

cUrl Script:

```
$url = "test.php";    
$content = json_encode(array('asdf'=>1));

$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
        array("Content-type: application/json"));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $content);

echo $json_response = curl_exec($curl);

$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if ( $status != 200 ) {
    die("Error: call to URL $url failed with status $status, response $json_response, curl_error " . curl_error($curl) . ", curl_errno " . curl_errno($curl));
}

echo" curl_error " . curl_error($curl) . ", curl_errno " . curl_errno($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

I cannot output anything in

test.php:

```
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_REQUEST);
    print_r($_POST);
    echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: do you get anything from `print_r($_POST);` ?

Comment: I do not get anything with print_r($_POST);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your POST did not contain a key/value pair, so there's nothing for $_POST to populate. You could try formatting it as a key/value pair, or you could just read from `php://input` in `test.php`:

```
<pre><?php var_dump(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

Comment: ok now this works but how would I be able to format it as a key/value pair.  Do you have an example ?

Comment: `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('json'=>$content));` should suffice; to quote the [curl_setopt](http://php.net/curl-setopt) docs: `This parameter can either be passed as a urlencoded string like 'para1=val1&para2=val2&...' or as an array with the field name as key and field data as value. If value is an array, the Content-Type header will be set to multipart/form-data.`

Answer (score 0):

Try this post [PHP CURL POST & GET Examples – Submit Form using PHP CURL](http://hayageek.com/php-curl-post-get/)

Comment: it doesn't show how to retrive the json being posted